# Problem to run P5.play using an online editor

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm developing a game where you have to code using P5.play mainly, I built an editor using the library codemirror to custom the editor.
So, my problem is the P5.play, when I use the editor for the first time and I run the code everything is fine, but if I click the Run button again, the console shows an error:

Uncaught error: you can only add sprites to a group

I don't know why this is happening, someone could help me?

Error screen
[image]

Running in the first time
[image]

Comment: Added inline images.

Comment: You'll have to show some code and a way for us to replicate your error, otherwise it's very hard to guess what you are doing and why it doesn't work. From your screenshot alone, it seems you are opening the file by double-clicking a HTML file. The url is `C:\Users\Desktop...` and this is never a good idea. Your url should always start with `http` and you should start a `localhost` server to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it, here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRFmUKngpjwn6J2VFNqvkc3HuxoEmeAV/view?usp=drivesdk